# Why does git stash pop acts as apply

Tags: git, git-stash

Anybody know why the drop part of the pop would not work for me?
pop is behaving like apply.

My process is:

```
git stash save "name of save"
git stash pop
```

then:

```
git stash list (and "name of save" will still be listed).
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z62QC.png)

Comment: Cannot reproduce this.  Can you copy-and-paste a complete terminal session that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when the changes stored in the stash cannot be applied clean and they leave the working tree in a conflicting state. `git stash pop` reports this in its output. You can also find if this is the case by running `git status`.

The reason behind this behaviour is very simple: you can run `git reset --hard` and `git stash pop` never happened. If you tried to pop the stash in the wrong context (wrong checked out branch) this way you can easily checkout the correct commit and try `git stash pop` again in the correct context.

Comment: That could be it. Always have merge issues with built css. 
#needsassinthebuild

Comment: Don't put the generated files in the repo. Put the build script instead and make it ready to run on a new computer (make it require all its dependencies when it runs, don't assume anything outside what the OS provides).

Comment: Nice idea but not an option :)

Comment: It's not just an idea, it's the current practice but, of course, each project is different and it might not fit yours :-)